# Почему mod_rewrite не работает на сервере?

Tags: .htaccess, apache, веб-программирование, mod-rewrite

Переношу сайт и столкнулся с проблемой: перестали работать ЧПУ, а т.к. сайт завязан на них, то и его функционал сильно пострадал - открывается все время главная страница, не зависимо от выбранного пункта меню. На старом хостинге все работало, локально на OpenServer все так же работает, но при переносе на VDS ... увы. Апач 2.4.6, ПХП 5.4, На других сайтах на этом сервере проблем с mod_rewrite нет, но там и ЧПУ более адекватно реализованы, а тут... Вот так:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^site\.ru$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://site.ru/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteBase /
php_flag register_globals on

ErrorDocument 404 /404.html

php_flag display_errors On
php_flag display_startup_errors On

#AddDefaultCharset windows-1251

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^priem/([0-9]+)/?$ index.php?menu=priem&month=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^catalog/$ index.php?catalog=ok [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^catalog/([a-zA-Z_0-9]+)/$ index.php?cat=$1&catalog=ok [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^catalog/([a-zA-Z_0-9]+)$ index.php?cat=$1&catalog=ok [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^catalog/([a-zA-Z_0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z_0-9]+).html index.php?cat=$1&catalog=ok&tov=$2 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^catalog/([a-zA-Z_0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z_0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z_0-9]+).html index.php?cat=$1&pages=$2&tov=$3&catalog=ok [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^catalog/([a-zA-Z_0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z_0-9]+)/?$ index.php?cat=$1&pages=$2&catalog=ok [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z_0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z_0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z_0-9]+).php index.php?menu=$1&pages=$2&doc=$3 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z_0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z_0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z_0-9]+).html index.php?menu=$1&pages=$2&doc=$3 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z_0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z_0-9]+)/?$ index.php?menu=$1&pages=$2 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z_0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z_0-9]+).html index.php?menu=$1&doc=$2 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z_0-9]+)/?$ index.php?menu=$1 [L]
```

Поддержка сервера за двое суток смогла родить только :

> В .htaccess существует множество дублирующихся правил, из-за которых
>   возникают подобные ошибки.  В данном случае, рекомендуется обратится
>   непосредственно к разработчику сайта.

Несколько часов танцев с бубном и комментированием построчно - не дали ровным счетом ничего. Сам mod_rewrite включен и ***phpinfo()*** его видит. Понимаю что собака где-то тут зарыта, но найти не могу. Прошу подсказать в каком направлении копать. Спасибо!

Comment: Почему вы думаете, что проблема с mod_rewrite? Он работает, раз открывается index.php (он же является целью всех перенаправлений). У вас возможно в index.php ветвление не функционирует. P.S. `php_flag register_globals on` это можете удалять, в php 5.4 ее нет.

Comment: Идея интересная, я ее проверю. Только тогда почему локально та же копия на тех же настройках сервера работает исправно?

Comment: Добавьте в начало index.php  строку `var_dump($_GET);` и проверьте так работает ли mod_rewrite добавляя нужные get переменные со значениями.

Comment: проверил, работает правильно. выводит, например array(1) { ["menu"]=> string(8) "new_year" } при адресе site.ru/new_year/ но при это отображается все та же главная страница =\

Comment: Вы бы в лог ошибок на сервере глянули, что там пишут. У вас проблема с роутером в php, а не в .htaccess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема как раз оказалась завязана на `register_globals on`, не знаю каким макаром оно работало на старом хостинге, но откатив версию php на 5.3 на новом сервере и немного поправив функцию-роутер все встало как надо.

Comment: Как временное решение - можно использовать. Но я советую вам переписать код сайта без использования `register_globals on` Прочитайте вот это http://php.net/manual/ru/security.globals.php от разработчиков php.